# Elastic Search Array Actions

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I would like to have an array of strings in an elasticsearch index. Suppose the array is a list of my recent restaurant choices. Each time I go to a new restaurant I add this to my list. I also would like to be able to find all of the users who have a particular restaurant in their list.

1. How can I create the index to handle this kind of mapping?
2. How can I update a list of restaurants?
3. How can I query each users' list of restaurants?

I am using ELK v 6.3.0.

Comment: [Elastic Array Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) This has every information you need. Have you tried anything yet, do you have any mapping? any specific question?

Comment: Thanks, that I have seen, but it doesn't answer my last two questions.

Comment: That site does not have the answers to my questions.  There are three specific questions at the end of my original post.  Please take a stab at the second question.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, @kahveci!  Looks great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question, you can use **painless script** to achieve it. This is pseudo code for the same

```
for(int i=0; i<ctx._source.RESTAURANTS.size();i++) {
 if(ctx._source.RESTAURANTS[i].ID == params.RESTAURANT_ID) {
    ctx._source.RESTAURANTS[i].NAME = params.RESTAURANT_NAME;
    break;
 }
}
```

params here is a Map, there you put the id of restaurant you want to update

```
esClient.prepareUpdate(indexName, type, documentId).setScript(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "replace script here", params)).execute().actionGet()
```

You can also write the query and pass the params

```
POST restaurant/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "for(int i=0; i<ctx._source.RESTAURANTS.size();i++) { if(ctx._source.RESTAURANTS[i].ID == params.RESTAURANT_ID) { ctx._source.RESTAURANTS[i].NAME = params.RESTAURANT_NAME; break;}}",
    "params": {
      "RESTAURANT_ID": 16,
      "RESTAURANT_NAME": "Updated Name"
    }
  }
}
```

This will update the document with id 1, and in nested document , check for restaurant with id 16, and update the name with "Updated Name"

For more details on how to use painless, [see this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/modules-scripting-painless.html)

Comment: Happy to help you.